# How can I get the id token from an Open ID Connect enterprise connection in Auth0

Tags: openid-connect, auth0, okta

I have an Auth0 SPA that I'm using in React, it has an Enterprise Connection that uses Open ID Connect to connect to an Okta App for Authentication. After the user logs in, I am able to retrieve the ID Token, but I'm getting the ID Token generated by Auth0. I need to get the ID token generated by Okta directly. Is there a way to do that? Is there a way in this scenario to get the ID Token generated by Okta and not the one from Auth0?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this documentation on Okta's developer site
https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react/

You can use this tutorial to create and Auth2.0 connection with Okta and retrieve Okta's id token. To request an id token, use 'openid profile' in the scope and it should return an id token along with an access token.

See this API documentation for an example of the body returned after successful authentication:https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#token